# example api gateway test event json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Where can I get an example json event for an API gateway call? Testing api gateway from the API Gateway console truncates most output so seems useless there.

I'd like to try sending my lambda an api gateway event directly via a json test event. Where are documented examples of the events api gateway sends lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API Gateway proxy event message examples are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html

However, if you are using the Lambda custom integration type then the event will contain whatever your API Gateway mapping template says it should contain.

Comment: ah something else here I wasn't understanding it seems. I _must_ use the proxy in order to get an "event" object right? If im using the lambda integration I handle the manipulation of that event via the api gateway templates and stuff right?

Comment: No you always get an event object. The API Gateway mapping templates define what the event object will look like when you are using the Lambda integration.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

(From link above)

```
{
    "resource": "/",
    "path": "/",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "requestContext": {
        "resourcePath": "/",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "path": "/Prod/",
        ...
    },
    "headers": {
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Host": "70ixmpl4fl.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e66d96f-7491f09xmpl79d18acf3d050",
        ...
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": {
        "accept": [
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
        ],
        "accept-encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate, br"
        ],
        ...
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": null,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "body": null,
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Github example from AWS docs: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/event.json